# Why __func__, __FUNCTION__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ aren't preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, standards

I've just noticed that `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` aren't treated as preprocessor macros and they're not mentioned on the *16.8 Predefined macro names* section of the Standard ([N4527 Working Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf)).

This means that they cannot be used in the string concatenation trick of [phase 6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases):

```
// Valid
constexpr char timestamp[]{__FILE__ " has been compiled: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__};
// Not valid!!!
template <typename T>
void die() { throw std::runtime_error{"Error detected in " __PRETTY_FUNCTION__}; }
```

As far as I know, the `__FILE__`, `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are translated to string literals as stated by the standard:

> #### 16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]
>
> `__DATE__`
>
> The date of translation of the source file: a **character string literal of the form `"Mmm dd yyyy"`**, where the names of the months are the same as those generated by the asctime function, and the first character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10. If the date of translation is not
>   available, an implementation-defined valid date shall be supplied.
>
> `__FILE__`
>
> The presumed name of the current source file (a **character string literal**).
>
> `__TIME__`
>
> The time of translation of the source file: a **character string literal of the form `"hh:mm:ss"`** as in the time generated by the asctime function.

`__func__` is mentioned by the standard as a function-local predefined variable of the form:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";
```

So the fact is that is a local variable hence the string concatenation trick doesn't works with it.

As for `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` aren't mentioned in the standard (are implementation defined?) but is a pretty safe bet to think that they would behave like `__func__`.

So the question is: Why `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are function-local static constant array of characters while `__FILE__`, `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are string literals? What's the rationale (if any) behind this decision?

Comment: It's even worse than you think, they're not even literals... if they were you could e.g. do a compiletime hash with a `constexpr` function in a constructor to get a super easy, super cheap mini-RTTI implementation (just good enough for serialization). When you try, the compiler will tell you "not a constant expression".

Comment: @Damon that's a pretty interesting observation, did you have an example of the behaviour you're describing? I would like to test it myself too.

Comment: I tried that very thing a year or so ago since it seemed like a nice way to make a RTTI system that has an overhead of storing a static integer per class. You need to store _something_, and a compiletime hash of the constructor's name (which is the class name) seemed ideal. A function's name is _obviously_ a compiletime constant, too (it doesn't really have much of a way of changing, does it!). But GCC didn't like the idea because none of the `__func__` -alikes (lowercase or uppercase, pretty or not) is a constant expression.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Expanding `__func__` at preprocessing time requires the preprocessor to know which function it's processing. The preprocessor generally doesn't know that, because parsing happens after the preprocessor is already done.

Some implementations combine the preprocessing and the parsing, and in those implementations, it would have been possible for `__func__` to work the way you'd like it to. In fact, if I recall correctly, MSVC's `__FUNCTION__` works like that. It's an unreasonable demand on implementations that separate the phases of translation though.

Comment: It would be nice to see if the Reflection Study Group (SG7) has a solution for that for C++1z

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall for two days thinking I didn't understand preprocessor directives. The best substitute I can think of is to replace the signature with a preprocessor definition that stores it, and use the variable on the next line to expand into the signature. Inside the function, the same variable can be stringified, concatenated, etc. as necessary. I don't like preprocessor solutions that put restrictions on the way code intended for the compiler is written, so I'm open to alternatives. If you need C strings, maybe sprintf into the error message? Otherwise STL?

Comment: @JohnP, but how would you override this variable from one function to the next? Wouldn't that break for more than one function?